# Make All Controller Methods Asynchronous

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Right now I have a method in my controller that just returns a static page.

```
public IActionResult CookiesPolicy()
{
    return View();
}
```

All my other controller methods are asynchronous and I would also like to make this method asynchronous. Can I do this? And if not, why not?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CookiesPolicy()
{
    return View();
}
```

Edit: If I do this Visual Studio tells me the method lacks await operators and will run synchronously.

Comment: Yes. You can do it.

Comment: @Shyju When I do I get told by Visual Studio that the method lacks await operators and will runs synchronously.

Comment: @David It's correct.  Internally, the async keyword triggers dotnet to create a new class (a state machine) to handle the async transitions.  If you are not awaiting anything in your method, there's no reason to make that state machine so the compiler is telling you this.  So either await something (making the internal state machine have something to do) or remove the async keyword and let the method run synchronously since that's what it would do anyway..

Comment: You only need Task/async if you do I/O operations that need to be awaited. CPU bound work and synch code (such as returning a view result) do not require async

Comment: @Tseng So for the most part my async work will be done when calling my API and awaiting the returned data?

Comment: Yea. For I/O everything that does involve filesystem (read, write), network (send/receive/web requests) or database qualifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CookiesPolicy()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(View());
}
```

But this doesn't really make your program better.

Comment: Shouldn't everything on the server side be asynchronous?

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you're thinking about performance, and this controller action is returning a mostly-static page then you would get far more bang for your buck using response caching.  If you do make this method async in the way I wrote, then you would expect your main thread to yield while the View is processed.  There could be a benefit to doing this, so saying 'doesn't really make your program better' may not be strictly true.